# Java WeakReference test not working as expected

Tags: java, weak-references

I have the code below. My expectation is that the code should print `Garbage Claimed` but it is consistently printing the value from the actual object which is `Test Object`. I have allowed the `testWeakReference()` frame to pop which should make `refTest` eligible for garbage collection. Then I have put the thread to sleep for 10seconds before testing whether the referent of the `WeakReference` has been garbage claimed.

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Optional;

public class WeakHashMapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WeakReference<RefTest> weakReference = testWeakReference();
        Thread.sleep(10000l);
        System.out.println(Optional.ofNullable(weakReference.get()).map(RefTest::getValue).orElse("Garbage claimed"));
    }

    private static WeakReference<RefTest> testWeakReference() throws InterruptedException {
        RefTest refTest = new RefTest("Test Object");
        WeakReference<RefTest> weakReference = new WeakReference(refTest);
        return weakReference;
    }

    public static class RefTest {
        private String value;

        public RefTest(String val){
            this.value = val;
        }

        public String getValue(){
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `System.gc()` instead of `sleep()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to assume that the GC would activate under such a low pressure test. You would have to do something that causes the GC to run.  There *is* a System.gc() method, but it is merely a hint to the GC, and may not do anything at all.

Comment: Ah that exlpains why even waiting for 10 seconds does not trigger the GC, there is no memory pressure.

Comment: Yep, that's why.  GC doesn't work the same as ref-counting. You shouldn't count on it being deterministic either.

Answer (score 1):

Weak references are collected upon garbage collection. Trigger a garbage collection (for example via `System.gc()`), or wait for one to occur due to memory allocation pressure, and `weakReference.get()` will return `null`.

Moreover, modern low-latency garbage collectors (ZGC and Shenandoah) delay collection of weak references, so if you use them, you would have to call `System.gc()` periodically (whose triggered collections do collect weak references).